# How do I get specific key values from a large object having multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sails.js

I working on sailjs 1.0 and receiving object from api call something like below.. but I need only specific data from this object.

```
var constructicons = [
  {
    name: 'Scrapper',
    form: 'Freightliner Truck',
    team: 'Decepticon',
    bodyPart: 'rightLeg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Hook',
    form: 'Mobile Crane',
    team: 'Decepticon',
    bodyPart: 'upperTorso'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bonecrusher',
    form: 'Bulldozer',
    team: 'Decepticon',
    bodyPart: 'leftArm'
  },
  {
    name: 'Scavenger',
    form: 'Excavator',
    team: 'Decepticon',
    bodyPart: 'rightArm'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mixmaster',
    form: 'Concrete Mixer',
    team: 'Decepticon',
    bodyPart: 'leftLeg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Long Haul',
    form: 'Dump Truck',
    team: 'Decepticon',
    bodyPart: 'lowerTorso'
  }
];
```

Now I want only the `name` and `bodyPart` key values of all arrays? How do i achieve this?

Comment: Hi Alexa. Welcome to Stackoverflow! . I am sure this question has been asked before. But anyways, where are you currently stuck at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

```js
let constructicons = [ { name: 'Scrapper', form: 'Freightliner Truck', team: 'Decepticon', bodyPart: 'rightLeg' }, { name: 'Hook', form: 'Mobile Crane', team: 'Decepticon', bodyPart: 'upperTorso' }, { name: 'Bonecrusher', form: 'Bulldozer', team: 'Decepticon', bodyPart: 'leftArm' }, { name: 'Scavenger', form: 'Excavator', team: 'Decepticon', bodyPart: 'rightArm' }, { name: 'Mixmaster', form: 'Concrete Mixer', team: 'Decepticon', bodyPart: 'leftLeg' }, { name: 'Long Haul', form: 'Dump Truck', team: 'Decepticon', bodyPart: 'lowerTorso' } ];

let result = constructicons.map(({name,bodyPart})=>({name,bodyPart}));
console.log(result);
```